# Bootstrap context is always returned as null with Azure Active Directory login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure Active Directory for user authentication in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. My user is getting authenticated and its identities are getting populated, but when I try to access the `bootstrapContext`, it's always null. I need this bootstrap context to get the token.

Comment: It is better to post your code in the question.

Comment: Did you find a solution?